# Jquery countdown that doesn't reset on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Vassilis Dourdounis jquery plugin, and I have created a countdown timer that hides some link on complete. But it restarts whenever the page is refreshed, and it shouldn't. It should finish the count and then disappear. Can anyone help, please?

**This is jquery:**

```
/*!
 * jQuery Countdown plugin v1.0
 * http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Vassilis Dourdounis
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */
(function($){

    $.fn.countDown = function (options) {

        config = {};

        $.extend(config, options);

        diffSecs = this.setCountDown(config);

        if (config.onComplete)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'callback', config.onComplete);
        }
        if (config.omitWeeks)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'omitWeeks', config.omitWeeks);
        }

        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .digit').html('<div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
        $(this).doCountDown($(this).attr('id'), diffSecs, 500);

        return this;

    };

    $.fn.stopCountDown = function () {
        clearTimeout($.data(this[0], 'timer'));
    };

    $.fn.startCountDown = function () {
        this.doCountDown($(this).attr('id'),$.data(this[0], 'diffSecs'), 500);
    };

    $.fn.setCountDown = function (options) {
        var targetTime = new Date();

        if (options.targetDate)
        {
            targetTime = new Date(options.targetDate.month + '/' + options.targetDate.day + '/' + options.targetDate.year + ' ' + options.targetDate.hour + ':' + options.targetDate.min + ':' + options.targetDate.sec + (options.targetDate.utc ? ' UTC' : ''));
        }
        else if (options.targetOffset)
        {
            targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetOffset.year + targetTime.getFullYear());
            targetTime.setMonth(options.targetOffset.month + targetTime.getMonth());
            targetTime.setDate(options.targetOffset.day + targetTime.getDate());
            targetTime.setHours(options.targetOffset.hour + targetTime.getHours());
            targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetOffset.min + targetTime.getMinutes());
            targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetOffset.sec + targetTime.getSeconds());
        }

        var nowTime = new Date();

        diffSecs = Math.floor((targetTime.valueOf()-nowTime.valueOf())/1000);

        $.data(this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);

        return diffSecs;
    };

    $.fn.doCountDown = function (id, diffSecs, duration) {
        $this = $('#' + id);
        if (diffSecs <= 0)
        {
            diffSecs = 0;
            if ($.data($this[0], 'timer'))
            {
                clearTimeout($.data($this[0], 'timer'));
            }
        }

        secs = diffSecs % 60;
        mins = Math.floor(diffSecs/60)%60;
        hours = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60)%24;
        if ($.data($this[0], 'omitWeeks') == true)
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24);
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }
        else 
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24)%7;
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }

        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'seconds_dash', secs, duration ? duration : 800);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'minutes_dash', mins, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'hours_dash', hours, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'days_dash', days, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'weeks_dash', weeks, duration ? duration : 1200);

        $.data($this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);
        if (diffSecs > 0)
        {
            e = $this;
            t = setTimeout(function() { e.doCountDown(id, diffSecs-1) } , 1000);
            $.data(e[0], 'timer', t);
        } 
        else if (cb = $.data($this[0], 'callback')) 
        {
            $.data($this[0], 'callback')();
        }

    };

    $.fn.dashChangeTo = function(id, dash, n, duration) {
          $this = $('#' + id);

          for (var i=($this.find('.' + dash + ' .digit').length-1); i>=0; i--)
          {
                var d = n%10;
                n = (n - d) / 10;
                $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:eq('+i+')', d, duration);
          }
    };

    $.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
        if (!duration)
        {
            duration = 800;
        }
        if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
        {

            $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
            $(digit + ' div.top').html((n ? n : '0')).slideDown(duration);

            $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function() {
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
                $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);


            });
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**This is HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/misc.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css"></link>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
    <h2>OFFER</h2>
    <img src="images/top.png" style="float:left;padding-left:15px;">
        <div id="top_offer">
                <p>REGISTER NOW AND GET SPECIAL BONUSES!</p>
            </div>
        <!-- Countdown dashboard start -->
        <div id="countdown_dashboard">



            <div class="dash minutes_dash">
                <span class="dash_title"></span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

            <div class="dash seconds_dash">
                <span class="dash_title"></span>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
                <div class="digit">0</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Countdown dashboard end -->


        <div class="info_message" id="complete_info_message">
            <a href="http://www.fxlider.com/lp4/education-kit" target="_blank"> <img src="images/offer.png" /> <p>Klikni ovde ► </p></a>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            // Set the Countdown
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
        targetOffset: {
            'day':      0,
            'month':    0,
            'year':     0,
            'hour':     0,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      60
        }, 
        // onComplete function
        onComplete: function() { $('#container').slideUp() }
    });
});
        </script>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

THANX!!!

Comment: It is normal and correct for JS to reset when a page is reloaded. You need to update the code to store the counter in a cookie (I notice you already include jquery.cookie.js on the page) or with html5 local storage, so that the current state persists beyond reloads.

Comment: Please, any directions or advice on how to do it..I have only used cookies so far to store a name on input, and I need this for tomorrow exam :(